# Why is a lulav from עיר הנדחת pasul because it lacks a shiur?

Tags: talmud-gemara, rashi, lulav-etrog-arba-minim, masechet-sukkah

In לולב הגזול, the first Mishna says a לולב של עיר הנדחת is pasul. Rashi explains that this is because it "lacks" the minimal length of 4 tefachim, since it is supposed to be burned and is halachically considered burned.
If we view such a lulav as if it's burnt, isn't the fact that it's not a לולב a more fundamental issue than the fact that it lacks its minimal length? It seems like Rashi's point (based on the Gemara) should be a secondary consideration and that we're missing the point.

Comment: I think you're taking it too literally.

Comment: As per @DoubleAA, i.e. the point is that the *shiur* gives the lulav *chashivus* and if it is *omed* to be burnt then it does not have that *chasivus*. (I.e. it is *nisbatlah* the *tzuras ha'chashivus* that is a *toldoh* of the *shiur*.)

Comment: For days 2-7. On day one, it's not לכם anyway because the איסור הנאה makes בעלות impossible.